# Why is Ni here?

Tags: particle-に

> 君は学生にすぎない

In Bunpro, this is translated to "You are nothing more than a student."

Can anyone explain why there must be a に after 学生?

Comment: [に過ぎない](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AB%E9%81%8E%E3%81%8E%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) is a set phrase.

Comment: If its a set phrase, then should I just forget grammar rules and memorize it?

Comment: There is also 「○○に過ぎる」 "to exceed something/to be better than something". As to the question why に, you are comparing something against a target or standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle に has many roles, and it can mark a subject of comparison. It's explained as the 11th definition of に in デジタル大辞泉:

> #### [に](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#:%7E:text=11-,%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83%E3%83%BB%E5%89%B2%E5%90%88%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%BA%96%E3%82%84%E3%80%81%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E8%B1%A1%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E3%81%99%E3%80%82,-%E3%80%8C%E5%90%9B%E2%80%95%E4%BC%BC%E3%81%A6)
>
> **11** 比較・割合の基準や、比較の対象を表す。「君―似ている」「一日―三回服用する」

Examples:

- AはBに勝る
  A is superior to him
- AはBに劣る
  B is inferior to him
- AはBに似ている
  A resembles B
- AはBに足りる
  A is enough for B
- 身に余る
  more than one deserves (set phrase)

That being said, ～に過ぎない is a fixed set phrase you have to memorize. It's always used in this form including the negation. 学生に過ぎる will never mean "You're more than a student".

Although highly bookish, there is also a pattern ～に過ぎる (e.g., 慎重に過ぎる "to be too cautious", 身に過ぎる "more than one deserves"). See: [「慎重すぎる」 and 「慎重に過ぎる」 - is there a difference?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18870/5010)